# Size Restriction of Uploaded Images Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, database

I want to limit the size of image(Base64) saved to the database. For example, I want the maximum size of image to be 100KB, how can I do that? I'm using Django.

Comment: Check this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373341/django-image-resizing-and-convert-before-upload

Comment: will check.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
#the size you want it to be, example for 2 mb is given below 
     max_upload_limit = 2*1024*1024
#override clean function to something like this 
 clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    pic = cleaned_data.get('picture')
    if pic is None:
        return
    if len(pic) > self.max_upload_limit:
        self.add_error('picture', "File must be < "+self.max_upload_limit_text+" bytes")
```

This show how to restrict image size using Django form.