# How do I get WSGI.py to serve images in static html fies?

Tags: python, image, jpeg, wsgi

Managing a Python (wsgi)-based site for a nonprofit & for historical reasons want to serve old (static) HTML from one subdomain.

Here is wsgi.py:

(Note that html/css files are in static/ folder, others in a subfolder of static/)
(This serves all the text w/ styles applied, but gives the alt text for images)

```
def application(env, start_response):
# some debugging queries to check what's getting passed in:
if env["QUERY_STRING"] == "env":
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type',
                                 'text/html; charset=utf-8')])
        return ['<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta charset="utf-8">',
                '<title>Environment</title>',
                repr(env),
               "</html>"]
    if env["QUERY_STRING"] == "req":
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type',
                                 'text/html; charset=utf-8')])
    return ['<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta charset="utf-8">',
            '<title>Incoming request dump</title>',
            "Scriptname: " + env["SCRIPT_NAME"] + "<br>",
            "Pathinfo: " + env["PATH_INFO"] + "<br>",
            "Querystring: " + env["QUERY_STRING"] + "<br>",
           "</html>"]

# the regular server code (runs OK):
    try:
        if env["PATH_INFO"] == "/": #root, no trailing '/'
            htmlfile = open("static/index.html")
            start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type',
                                 'text/html; charset=utf-8')])
        return [htmlfile.read()]
    elif env["PATH_INFO"].endswith(".html"):
        htmlfile = open("static" + env["PATH_INFO"]) #
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type',
                                 'text/html; charset=utf-8')])
        return [htmlfile.read()]
    elif env["PATH_INFO"].endswith(".css"):
        cssfile = open("static" + env["PATH_INFO"]) #
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type',
                                 'text/css; charset=utf-8')])
        return [cssfile.read()]

# This generates "Internal server error:"
    elif env["PATH_INFO"].endswith(".jpg") or
         env["PATH_INFO"].endswith(".JPG"):
        jpegfile = open("static" + env["PATH_INFO"]) #
        jpegdata = jpegfile.read()
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg'),
             ('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes'),
             ('Content-Length', str(len(jpegdata))),
             ('Connection', 'close')])
        return [jpegdata]
except Exception as e:
    return ['<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Oops',
            "</title>Can't read file on server!</html>"]
```

-- AFAICS a WSGI app has to return an iterable containing strings; images are bytes objects, but the server is running Python 2.7, & 'bytes' is an alias for 'string' -- so that shouldn't be a problem. I can't find any info on encoding in this situation, & HTTP handles octets. I've tried all sorts of variations & Googled (R) this for days, but still stuck. How do I get this silly thing to serve an image?

Answer (score 4):

This must be enough

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    data = open('image.jpg', 'rb').read()
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type': 'image/jpeg'), 
                              ('content-length', str(len(data)))])
    return [data]
```

Maybe the error is not what you think. Check Apache's log file for errors - /var/log/apache2/error.log (In case you are using Apache)

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001068/creating-dynamic-images-with-wsgi-no-files-involved

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turned out to be a separate issue: the Python compiler had a problem with the 'or' in the test. I fixed this by using 'env["PATH_INFO"].lower()'

Thanks for response,
Ed